# Set title of navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've tried everything I can think of here.

```
self.navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
self.navigationBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
    self.title = @"Title";
    self.navigationBar.topItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
[self.view addSubview:self.navigationBar];
```

I've tried all of these in the hope that one would work, but none of them have. How do i change the title of this navigation bar? This is inside the init method of a UIViewController.

Comment: It all depends on where the navigation bar is initialized.

Comment: As @stavash said, you may need to specify where the bar was initialized. If it happened in another class, for example, you wouldn't use self, but rather an instance of that class. So if you made it happen elsewhere, it would be #import SomeClassName and then in the header SomeClassName *className; then... you can do className.navigationBar.title = "Title";

Comment: By the way, the view isn't ready in the init method so I would strongly suggest transferring whatever code you decide to viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your custom NavigationBar's items array.  You should pass in an array with one item that has your specified title:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [[[UINavigationBar alloc] init] autorelease];

UINavigationItem *navItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"] autorelease];
bar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
```

Answer (score 1):

This always works for me:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why you want to put it in init, usually I would rather put this code in viewDidLoad.

However, the thing that is problematic with your code is that when you init the UINavigationBar, it does not have any items in its items array. Thus, you're actually sending a message to a nil, which will not crash your program, but will not do anything.

This is what I'd do.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    navigationBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[UINavigationItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title"]]];
    navigationBar.topItem.titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a navigation controller then

```
self.title = @"My Title";
```

should do it in iOS 7.